# How to avoid message Publisher Unknown when download Jnlp?

Tags: java, jnlp

[image]
We have developed an application which uses a jar which is downloaded vìa Jnlp. It is downloaded each time a button is pressed so message always appears. We have done a research looking a solution and it is Buy a Certificate to sign the code. Is there another possible, real and practical solution? We know also is appears because the operating system which is Windows 10 Pro. We have no try in other operating systems.